# what is the correct way to format a datetime in SQL server datetime field

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have a dateTime object in C# and i want to do an insert into SQL Server datetime field.  What is the correct format for this?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be building up SQL strings in code. Instead you should look at using either stored procs, parameterized queries or an ORM. Any of these would resolve your problem with formatting as you just pass the object, you don't have to do any string formatting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct way to do this is by using a parameterised query, *not* text formatting. Then you can just use a strongly-typed [`SqlDbType.DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) parameter.

(If you absolutely must use text formatting to do this - *and I strongly recommend against it* - then something like `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss` should do the trick.)

Comment: wouldn't i still be passing in a string into the parameterized query and have the same issue ?

Comment: Actually, the format that is guaranteed to work on any SQL Server regardless of language and regional settings would be `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss` (without the dashes - those caused trouble in certain language settings)

Comment: @marc_s: I've updated the answer to use the safe-in-all-circumstances format.

Comment: Try to query, with the .net classes a table indexed on a DateTime column using a BETWEEN dt1 AND dt2 criteria, and you'll quickly find a use for either query hints or inline values, both of which require the correct formatting (hint: the query optimizer isn't always smart enough to figure out that you only want a few rows, tablescan here we go)

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @Luke's answer I came across this bug just the other day.

The `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format has a locale/language issue on SQL Server 2005 (an example is French), but is fixed in SQL 2008:

So, do NOT use this format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (space separator).

Only use: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` ("T" separator) or `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss` (no dash delimiters)

Important if you're generating scripts that include `datetime` constants.

See [Jamie Thomson's article on SQL Blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/12/08/unambiguous-date-formats-t-sql-tuesday-001.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

a sample [took from here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_2191631_3/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables.htm)

```
     SET NOCOUNT ON 
     CREATE TABLE X(EXAMPLE INT, D SMALLDATETIME)
     -- EXAMPLE 1
     SET DATEFORMAT MDY
     INSERT INTO X VALUES (1, '10/30/56')
     -- EXAMPLE 2
     SET DATEFORMAT YDM
     INSERT INTO X VALUES (2, '56/31/10')
     -- EXAMPLE 3 
     SET DATEFORMAT YMD
     INSERT INTO X VALUES (3, '56/10/31')
     SELECT * FROM X
```